How to deal with an oscilating and large-range numerical integration?
Thank you for reading my question!
We are trying to calculate a correlation:
$$
        \begin{align}
            \rho_{ij}\approx\frac{\left|\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-r}^{r}\frac{e^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(d_i(x,y)-d_j(x,y))}}{d_i(x,y)d_j(x,y)}dxdy\right|^2}{\left|\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-r}^{r}\frac{1}{d_i^2(x,y)}dxdy\right|\left|\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-r}^{r}\frac{1}{d_j^2(x,y)}dxdy\right|}
\tag{1}
        \end{align}
$$
where
$$
d_i(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2+z_i^2},\quad d_j(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-x_j)^2+(y-y_j)^2+z_j^2},\\
(x_i,y_i,z_i)=(0.2m,0.1m,1m),\quad (x_j,y_j,z_j)=(0m,0m,1.1m),\quad\lambda=0.003m
$$
The locations $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ and $(x_j,y_j,z_j)$ are changable. An example is shown above.
In fact, these integrations come from summations (or matrix operations like inner product and norm). The sizes of the vectors are too big, which is beyond normal computation capacity. Hence we choose to use integrations as shown in $(1)$. We have already got a closed-form approximation and we want to verify it by the numerical integration here. FYI, I proved that both the numerator and the denominator approximately increase w.r.t $\log^2{r}$, which means they are all going to $\infty$ as $r$ goes to $\infty.$ But the ratio between them would be a constant as $r\rightarrow\infty$, i. e.,  $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}=c$, where $c$ is a constant.
The problem comes from the integration in the numerator:
$$
\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-r}^{r}\frac{e^{j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(d_i(x,y)-d_j(x,y))}}{d_i(x,y)d_j(x,y)}dxdy
$$
When I tried to integrate it with the following matlab code:
function cor = correlation_usw_integration(useri,userj,lambda,range) 
% Function: Calculate the sum capacity based on SPW and UPW separately.
% Input:
%  Bs_pos: Position of BS.
%  useri: Position of useri.
%  userj: Position of userj.
%  lambda: wavelength
%  range: integration ragne r
% Output:
%  cor: the correaltion (as shown in (1) )
beta = 1;% Power at reference distance
k= 2*pi/lambda;
di = @(x,y) sqrt((useri(1)-x).^2 + (useri(2)-y).^2 + (useri(3)-0).^2);
dj = @(x,y) sqrt((userj(1)-x).^2 + (userj(2)-y).^2 + (userj(3)-0).^2);
channel_func_SPW = @(d) sqrt(beta)./d.*exp(-1j.*k.*d); %Spherical wave model
channel_SPW_abs_s = @(x,y) abs(channel_func_SPW(di(x,y))).^2;
channe2_SPW_abs_s = @(x,y) abs(channel_func_SPW(dj(x,y))).^2;
integrand = @(x,y) beta*exp(1j*k*(di(x,y)-dj(x,y)))./di(x,y)./dj(x,y);
cor = abs(integral2(integrand,-range,range,-range,range)).^2/...
    abs(integral2(channel_SPW_abs_s,-range,range,-range,range))/...
    abs(integral2(channe2_SPW_abs_s,-range,range,-range,range));

It would show the warning as
Warning: Reached the maximum number of function evaluations (10000). The result fails the global error test. 
> In integral2Calc>integral2t (line 129)
In integral2Calc (line 9)
In integral2 (line 105)
In correlation_usw_integration (line 19)
In correlation_usw_verification (line 26) 

I know the integrand oscillates fast at first and becomes slower as it gets away from the origin. And I tend to make $r$ as large as possible. Hence, the integration is oscillating and large-range at the same time. It might be hard to get an accurate integration result. I need some suggestions on how to get an accurate result.
I would really appreciate it if you could give me any suggestions. Thank you in advance!
